# Вызов меню по нажатию на правую кнопку в WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Есть некоторый DataGridView.

Нужно при нажатии на правую кнопку отобразить контекстное меню с действиями над этой ячейкой.

Подскажите, как это делается?

Comment: Самый очевидный вариант - задать ContextMenu для шаблона ячейки. Проблема в чем?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Присоединяем контекстное меню к `DataGridView`.

Подписываемся на событие `ContextMenuStrip.Opening`:

```
private void ContextMenuStrip_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var point = dataGridView.PointToClient(contextMenuStrip.Bounds.Location);
    var info = dataGridView.HitTest(point.X, point.Y);

    // Отменяем показ контекстного меню, если клик был не на ячейке
    if (info.RowIndex == -1 || info.ColumnIndex == -1)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

В обработчике клика нужных пунктов контекстного меню, относящихся к ячейкам, пишем:

```
private void ToolStripItem_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var point = dataGridView.PointToClient(contextMenuStrip.Bounds.Location);
    var info = dataGridView.HitTest(point.X, point.Y);

    // Работаем с ячейкой
    var value = dataGridView[info.ColumnIndex, info.RowIndex].Value;
}
```

---

Другой вариант.

Показываем контекстное меню вручную, когда оно необходимо. Для этого подписываемся на событие `DataGridView.CellContextMenuStripNeeded`:

```
private void DataGridView_CellContextMenuStripNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellContextMenuStripNeededEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex != -1 && e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        contextMenuStrip.Show(Cursor.Position);
    }
}
```

При этом не нужно подсоединять меню к самому `DataGridView`. И удаляем обработку события `ContextMenuStrip.Opening`.
Обработчики событий `ToolStripItem.Click` остаются без изменений.

Comment: А если у меня мн такого вида Статус->Список Статусов. Как мне по некоторому условия делать доступными выборочно элементы из списка статусов?

Comment: Т.е в меню есть подменю. Как мне работать с элементами подменю? И на какое событие мне вешать логику? Opening?

Comment: Ну да, можно в Opening скрывать/показывать пункты подменю. Можно перед вызовом Show.